# 'options' redefined near 'options'

Tags: root, bind

I'm trying to configure my named.conf for my root server but when I run named-checkconf I get the following message

```
/etc/bind/named.conf:13: 'options' redefined near 'options'
```

My named.conf is looking like this:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

options {
          directory "/etc/bind";
          listen-on port 53 { any; };
          allow-query { any; };
#         forwarders { 142.204.1.2; };
#         recursion yes;
        };
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "root.zone"
};

zone "20.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type hint;
        file "igurvich-rev.db";
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved. I had a redundancy trying to use both the options in the named.conf and the named.conf.options so I just edited line 1 out